# how to change http://www.myexample.com:3000 to http://wwww.myexample.com in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to ruby, can any one help me in explaining "how to change http://www.myexample.com:3000 to http://wwww.myexample.com in ruby?"

Comment: I think this needs to be tagged ruby-on-rails (if that's what you're using).

Comment: Are you asking how to change a string representing a URL from one port to another, or are you asking how to get a particular web server to run on port 80 instead of port 3000? If the latter, what server or framework are you running _(e.g. Ruby on Rails, Thin, Webrick, Sinatra, Mongrel)_?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse('http://www.myexample.com:3000')

uri.port = nil
uri.host.sub!('www', 'wwww')

uri.to_s # => http://wwww.myexample.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what web server you're using, but in general, try adding a `-p 80` option to the command line when starting up the web server.

For example, with the Thin web server, you'd run: `thin -p 80 start`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your using webrick, pass `--port 80` on the command line when running your server

Answer (score 0):

port 3000 is the rails server default port. You can avoid this 3000 by getting your rails app behind apache/ passenger (normally the production setup)

By that way apache and passenger will do the routings and you can view your app at 
http://www.example.com

Following will be helpful

passenger - http://www.modrails.com/
rails casts - http://railscasts.com/episodes/122-passenger-in-development

hope this helps

cheers

sameera